# onProgressUpdate misses some publishes

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask

Is it possible that some calls publishProgress missed by onProgressUpdate? I mean is it possible there may be one transfer miss between doInBackground and onProgressUpdate callbacks with using publishProgress call. Because I see that.

```
class DoSomething extends AsyncTask Void, String, Void {
  String[] S = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

  void doInBackground(Void... ps) {

    for(String s : S) {      
      publishProgress(s);
    }
   }

  void onProgressUpdate(String... vs) {

   Log.d("", vs[0]);
 }
```

What i am encountering that resulting

a b b d

what happening to c?
**Note:** This is just illustration of my application, and this happens sometimes(not at all run), i could not write all the codes here because its too complicated. But in summary this is happening. 
So any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. I dug deep and found the answer that: message transmission between `doInBackground` and `onProgressUpdate` is not serial that is asynchronous (from the base class name). Any call in `doInBackground` with `publishProgress(xx)` will eventually reach to `onProgressUpdate` but not one-to-one.
For example, very dummy demonstration:

```
doInBackgroud() {
String s;
 for(i=1 to 10) {
   s = i.toString();
   publishProgress(s);
  }
}

onProgressUpdate(String par) {
Log.d(par);
}
```

can be result as: 1 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7
What tha ?
Dont worry, we sending the local variable s (in doinback.) by reference and by the time `onProgressUpdate` invoked and it is logging its value, there is probability that `doInBackground` is changing the value of s. That results unexpected value in the `onProgressUpdate`. But all publishProgress calls invoke the `onProgressUpdate` method.
If we wrote:

```
doInBackgroud() {

 for(i=1 to 10) {
  String s = i.toString();
   publishProgress(s);
  }
}

onProgressUpdate(String par) {
Log.d(par);
}
```

this time under normal conditions, result must be : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
and this is what we expect, isn't it?
if there is better idea, i would like to hear that
And any comments will be well-welcomed.
**Note:** Maybe too simple case, but saved my week.