# OnProgressUpdate are called at once time after end of for cycle

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to update progress bar using AsyncTask and method onProgressUpdate. I have for cycle in method doInBackground, but progress are called at once time after for cycle is ended.
A tried add log above publishUpdate line and log is called in real time.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String message = "Inicialized";

    JsonApiParser jsonApiParser = new JsonApiParser(NationalParks.getContext());

    callList = getInicializationCallList();


    int count = callList.size(), id;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        String call = callList.get(i);
        String[] stringArray = call.split("/");

        try {
            id = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[stringArray.length - 1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            id = 0;
        }

        try {
            if (call.contains("info")) {
                JSONObject json = Request.getParkInfo(id);
                jsonApiParser.insertPark(json);
            } else if (call.contains("category-lodging")) {
                JSONObject json = Request.getLodgingCategory(id);
                jsonApiParser.insertLodgingCategory(json);
            } 

            Log.e("call", call); // this called in real time
            publishProgress((int) (((i + 1) / (float) count) * 100)); // this called after for cycle is ended
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return message;
        }
    }

    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = NationalParks.getSharedPreferences().edit();
    edit.putLong("lastUpdate", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000);
    edit.commit();

    return message;
}

...

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    Log.e("Progress", progress[0] + "%");
    progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
}
```

Know anybody why?

Comment: Why this row?     "int count = callList.size(), id;"

Are you sure the for cycle is not executed just one time?

Comment: It's faster if count is defined. I think cycle is not executed just on time, because, log is writted step by step.

Comment: This answer may solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6971409/1507512

Probably onProgressUpdate is called more than once but always says the last value of i (cause of the asynchronous call of onProgressUpdate once you call publishProgress).